# Custom Event on CDS (Context Driven Services) on Spartacus Storefront

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I set the CDS on Spartacus, following the guide on the official Spartacus documentation. But I could not figure out how to set a “View Product Page” event that is triggered when a product is viewed. Any one knows the right way to configure it on Spartacus ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with CDS, but as far as I know, you can subscribe and react to  ProductDetailsPageEvent using Spartacus event service.

Kindly refer to below source code written in your app.module.js:

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(events: EventService) {

    const event$ = events.get(ProductDetailsPageEvent);
    event$.subscribe((event) => console.log('ProductDetailsPageEvent is fired: '
       + event));
  }
}
```

details could be found in Spartacus document:

https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/event-service/#page-title

Best Regards,
Jerry

Comment: Agreed with Jerry. That said, in production code, please make sure you dispose any subscriptions in `ngOnDestroy()` method of any component or service that created the subscription. Otherwise it may cause memory leaks.

Comment: Indeed that was the solution for many other cases like that. Thanks for your help!